# MySQL - Strange symbols while using urllib in Python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, urllib

I am using `urllib` in python 2.7 to retrieve webpages from the internet. After parsing the data and storing it on the database, i get the following symbols `â€“` and `â€` and `â€”` and so on. I wanted to know how these symbols are generated and how to get rid of it? Is it an encoding issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is an encoding issue, make sure sure when you parse your data it doesn't encrypt it or turn it into byte encoded format. Those characters means your computer can't read the data that is being stored, so it isn't being stored in a data type that we can read.